# Redis data being deleted after some time on its own

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-server

I have a problem with Redis db, it works not as intended. I have a Telegram bot that gets data from user and stores it in the Redis db. It writes and stores data correctly, but after some time data just gets deleted. Why is that?
The bot and db run on a remote server and don't get rebooted. But maybe Redis does reboots automatically? I don't know.
Note that I use Redis as primary database.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is not a permanent storage, data gets flushed when server gets restarted unexpectedly or a flush command is executed. So try using other databases for your exact need.

In Case if your db doesnt restarts, maybe you might have set expiry for Redis Keys.If no expiry is set, kindly check maxmemory-policy in redis.conf your keys get flushed when you run out of memory.

Comment: can't I turn off those data flushes?

Comment: Yes. Redis supports persistence. Details are here: https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/

Comment: In Case if your db doesnt restarts, maybe you might have set expiry for Redis Keys.If no expiry is set, kindly check maxmemory-policy in redis.conf your keys get flushed when you run out of memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).